# React native sorts array in useEffect but does not print it correctly

Tags: react-native

What am I doing wrong here? https://snack.expo.dev/@kickbk/names
Click on F to sort by `first_name` or L to sort by `last_name`.
You will see that:

1. When you load it, it should be filtered by `first_name`. It is not showing it sorted.
2. when you click on L to sort by `last_name`, it displays the data sorted by `first_name`
3. Then when you click on F to sort by `first_name`, it displays the data sorted by `last_name`
   In fact, it sorts the data correctly, but only renders it the next time you sort it. Why?
   I made it very easy to follow on the issue I'm getting. Just check the logs and see what it prints.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve the issue? I cannot seem to reproduce it on snack, so the code on snack works as expected. I ran it in web version and when I click 'L' it sorts by last_name. When I click 'L' again, it does nothing and the result is still sorted by last_name as expected

Comment: Yes, resolved. See below for explanation as to why this was happening.

Answer (score 0):

`LocalCompares` doesn't work with sort you need to use it like this:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    console.log("promoters changed", { filterByName });
    let filteredResults;
    if (filterByName) {
      filteredResults = [...filteredPromoters].sort((a, b) => {
        if ( filterByName === "first") {
            if(a.first_name < b.first_name) { return -1; }
            if(a.first_name > b.first_name) { return 1; }
            return 0;
        } else {
            if(a.first_name > b.first_name) { return -1; }
            if(a.first_name < b.first_name) { return 1; }
            return 0;
        }
      }
      );
    }
    setFilteredPromoters(filteredResults);
  }, [filterByName]);
```

I create a working example you can check it from [here](https://snack.expo.dev/@louay12/names).

Answer (score 0):

I learned something today. The reason sorting was not working properly with my example was because sort modifies the array in place, and you can't directly modify state variables. Creating a new array with a spread operator is a way to handle it: `[...filteredPromoters].sort`, which is also what makes Louay's example work. Although it is a working solution, I believe it's important to mark this explanation as the actual solution to the problem.